# How can a team of 2 or 3 safely traverse a narrow, exposed snow ridge?

Tags: safety, mountaineering, belaying

Assume a team of 2-3 people intend to traverse a very exposed ridge at altitude. What are the main hazards and how can they be mitigated?

The type of ridge in question is covered in snow (various types of, maybe even some ice) and falls off steeply to both sides. The mountaineers follow the ridge to ascend/descend from a peak, generally following the highest point or close to the highest point of the ridge. The inclination of the ridge itself can vary from up- to downhill and various steepnesses (an answer may need to specify applicable steepness for different techniques). Examples of such ridges are the Piz Palü traverse or Bianco ridge to Bernina.

Comment: There are too many questions rolled into one. As it stands, this is way too broad.

Comment: Don't short rope: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/18397/is-short-roping-death-roping/18408#18408

Comment: @StrongBad: What about short-rope+10m of slack to throw in case of somebody is slipping?

Comment: This question has received votes to close it. I'm not experienced enough to answer questions of this type (and so won't vote), however, this question does not appear to my (admittedly inexperienced in this field) eye to ask anything specific. "What is the best way to [go on a mountain with a very exposed ridge]." Example lame answer I could give: The best way to go anywhere is to walk - don't belay or use any rope, just walk around. See? I think you need to describe what you're trying to do. Go around the ridge? Climb the ridge itself? What?

Comment: May I suggest that you alter your question to something akin to. "Assume a team of 2-3 people intend to traverse a very exposed ridge at altitude. What are the main hazards and how can they be mitigated?" A good answer could explain how excessive focus on one danger (slipping) might expose you to another (corniches)

Comment: I guess I don't have any problems understanding the question because I know both mentioned example ridges. They are prototypical highly-exposed snow ridges where you make headway (up or down) on top or close to the highest part of the ridge. Asking about what techniques are appropriate in this scenario seems totally relevant and clear (while dangerous if followed without additional training, but that's true for most content on this site). cerv21 please correct or adjust if I got your intent wrong.

Comment: @imsodin The original close votes were to the original question as stated. It has changed radically since then.